# Add up numbers in a for each PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to add some numbers in a `foreach loop` in my PHP code. I am getting a `percentage` of numbers in a `while loop` in my MySQL query for each result that I get in my PHP page.

All I need to do is to add up the final values in and show them as total.

This is how I make up the percentage in my while loop in my MySQL query:

```
$percentage = 10;
$totalWidth = $fees;

$new_width = ($percentage / 100) * $totalWidth;
```

The `$fees` value is dynamic and it is different for each result in my while loop. the code above works as it should.

Now I want to add up all the values of `$new_width`. For example:

If one result's $new_width is 25 and the other one is 10 and another one is 5, I need to do this: `$total = 25 + 10 + 5;`

So I tried something like this:

```
$total = 0;

foreach($new_width as $var) {
   $total = $var + $var; 
}

echo $total;
```

but the above code doesn't really make sense and it won't do anything at all.

Could someone please advise on this matter?

Comment: Set `$total` to 0 before your while loop. Once you've generated `$new_width`, add that value to `$total`. You don't need that second foreach loop at all.

Comment: If you didn't already saw it you can take a tour here: http://stackoverflow.com/tour and see how this site works!

Comment: You are redefining $total inside the `foreach` loop thus reseting every time

Comment: @Rizier123, it would be good to know the reason behind you sharing that link! I find it unrelated to my question unless you have saw something in my question that I'm missing!

Comment: @Jackson Because i see that you are member since today and i think it's good to show you the link which show's you quickly how this site works and is made. And all possibilities on the site. (e.g. That you know where and how to comment, How to edit your question and so on :D just that you can look into that and find the stuff if you need it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you want to change this line in your while loop so you get an array:

```
$new_width = ($percentage / 100) * $totalWidth;
```

to this:

```
//Declare it as an array before your while loop
$new_width = array();
//In your while loop
$new_width[] = ($percentage / 100) * $totalWidth;
        //^^ See here
```

After this you just have to change the line in your foreach loop like this:

```
$total = $var + $var;
```

to this:

```
$total += $var;
```

(If you want you also can do this in your while loop)

Answer (score 1):

If you have an array of numbers and you want to calculate the sum of those numbers, you should use [array_sum()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php).

Answer (score 0):

According to the logic, you are setting the total to 2 X $var.

My answer is very similar, but you add it to the total which is outside of the loop and the value will keep growing:

```
$total = 0;

foreach($new_width as $var) {
   $total += $var; 
}

echo $total;
```

Or simply as stated before, if it is the only value in the array:

```
$total = array_sum($new_width);
```